# Google Cloud Translate php API returning unicode characters instead of the characters themselves

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Cloud Translate PHP sdk to translate strings from a JSON file, the problem is it returns the translated strings with unicode characters instead of the real characters, so I have to search and replace each one which is quite a hassle...

Example:

```
"Exp\u00e9riences"
```

Is there a way to return the characters instead of the weird unicode thingy?

My method:

```
public function translateJsonFile(Request $request)
    {
        $htmlString = '';
        $source = 'en';
        $target = 'it';

        $key = 'My key';

        $translate = new TranslateClient([
            'key' => $key
        ]);

        //$trans = new GoogleTranslate();

        $newArray = [];
        $json = File::get(base_path() . '/resources/lang/english.json');
        $array = json_decode($json, true);

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
        {
            //$result = $trans->translate($source, $target, $value);

            $text_translated = $translate->translate($value, [
                'source' => $source,
                'target' => $target
            ])['text'];

            $newArray[$key] = $text_translated;
            //sleep(1);
            usleep( 500000 );
        }

        $fileName = '/temp/translated-'.rand(1,1000).'.json';

        Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName, json_encode($newArray));

        return response()->json([
            'newArray' => $newArray,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass an additional paramenter in the request, the format parameter.

if not passed it default to html and you get the result you are getting, in your case you should use text.
you can see it here https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate